# Ubuntu 20.10 Macbook Air 2011 bluetooth issue

Tags: bluetooth, macbook

Running Ubuntu 20.10 on a Macbook Air 2011. When bluetooth paired a pair Razor Anzu smartglasses I noticed that something is wrong with how bluetooth i configured. It works very poorly and the sound in the glasses is so bad it cannot be used. When rebooting to macOS (have dual boot) it works perfect. I am just posting this to inform and hoping that this problem will be corrected one day.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in Ubuntu 20.10:

`sudo systemctl restart bluetooth`

Edit 1: You could also install Blueman. It is an amazing Bluetooth manager. You can install it from the software center or via the terminal: `sudo apt install blueman`